# Cannot use Bitnami Node.js for building Cordova App. Because npm not recognized

Tags: android, node.js

I am downloaded Node.js and Apache Ant from **Bitnami**. And set **Environmental Variables** for the **Android SDK**, **Java JDK**, **Apache ANT** and for **NODE.js**.

I have checked the PATH by **echo %PATH%** command in **CMD** and it results as

- C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
- C:\WINDOWS\system32;
- C:\WINDOWS;
- C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
- C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
- C:\Program Files(x86)\WinSCP\;
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin;
- C:\Bitnami\apache-ant-1.9.2-bin\apache-ant-1.9.2;
- C:\Softwares\android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools;
- C:\Softwares\android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;
- C:\Bitnami\nodejs-0.12.2-0;

But it always showing like this,

- C:>npm -v
- 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

Please suggest for fixing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

The path for npm and cordova are present in **nodejs\node_modules** folder. So refer all paths from **use_nodejs** file. Please follow the steps.

Open the Command Prompt from Windows. And type `C:\>set`. From this you can get all system Variables and paths.

Open the **use_nodejs** which is the windows batch file from **C:\xxx\Bitnami\nodejs-0.12.2-0** and type `C:\>set`, from this you can get all system Variables and paths but which is looking different.

Compare the variables and paths from both command prompt and you can get ideas of paths.

Change the path in Windows Command Prompt like `setx NODE_HOME "C:\Bitnami\nodejs-0.12.2-0\nodejs\node_modules"` from the **use_nodejs command promt** paths. Like this change whatever paths you want to add.